# Responsive slide up/down div onclick

Tags: jquery, fadein, show-hide, scrollto, slidedown

I have a link that when clicked needs to slide up or slide down (depending on the state) a DIV that contains a responsive full width video. As its responsive and its a widescreen video the height cannot be fixed (my existing code does this and needs to change). This DIV (containing the video) must be hidden on page load.

I have my existing code here: http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/ which works to a certain extent in that it hides/shows the video. However, the main problem is that the height of the video is visible on page load and creates a blank space.

I need the video to slide down/up AND fade in/out from the horizontal black bar whilst the content beneath this area, gets pushed down or pulled up when the state of the showreel changes.

A bonus would be to add functionality that when the link is clicked the page scrolls to that opening DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding you add in your css is causing the gap:

```
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16/9 ratio */
padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
```

You could animate in this padding when it's being shown, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/3/), but it seems to cause the video to go messy on Firefox.

I'd calculate the correct height before trying to animate to that height, and not use padding at all. To get the correct height for a 16/9 video, you just divide the width by 16 then multiply it by 9. Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/2/

To auto-scroll the page to the top of the video you can put this in as the animate's complete function:

```
function(){$('html, body').scrollTop($('#showreel').offset().top);}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see what you mean. Is there a way to not animate the padding calculation? So for example, I click the button, a calculation of the video size needed to fill the width is made then a wrapper DIV slides down (to fit the calculated size) and then the video fades in over the top? And vice-versa when you hide the video? Can this be done?

Comment: Yeah thats great, could this method be responsive too? For example, when you resize the browser the video doesn't expand with the window (leaving black bars at the side), could this be made responsive?

Comment: Yep you can set an on window resize function, like this http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/8/

Answer (score 0):

the blank space is from the padding you set on the #showreel, just remove it.

have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/D5EMp/1/

the biggest problem is how to know the size of the video. but in my mind, it's impossible to know a video's size before it is loaded. and accessing to iframe will lead to some cross-domain problems.

em, you can search for an another way to solve this problem, not just by technology

that's my idea

Comment: Regarding the cross domain issues, the Vimeo video will be changed to a video that will be hosted on my own server (using HTML5). I don't have this video yet so using Vimeo as astop gap solution :)